# Hapijs: Performance tuning for lots of concurrent requests

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Are there any special tuning tips for strengthening an API built on top of the hapijs framework?

Especially if you have lots of concurrent request (+10000/sec) that are accessing the DB?

- I'm using PM2 to start my process in "cluster mode" to be able to load-balance to different cores on the server
- I don't need to serve static content, so there's no apache/nginx proxy

***update 17:11***

Running tests with 1000 requests/sec (with loader.io) results in this curve - ok, so far. but I'm wondering if there is still room for improvements.
(hardware: 64gb / 20 core digital ocean droplet)

[image: Running test with 1000 requests/sec]

Comment: You should consider use a reverse nginx proxy anyway, even without static content, for security reasons. Also, when using the reverse proxy, you can launch the app multiple times, on different ports, and do the load-balancing with nginx.

Comment: @Qualcuno security isn't an issue right now. I was wondering if the nginx part doesn't add more overhead than performance gain ... but I will try and run some test with PM2/hapi vs nginx/hapi.

Comment: That's why I posted a comment and not an answer. It was just a heads-up, having a reverse proxy is always a good idea IMHO. We still use PM2 to fork (not cluster) multiple instances of the app and keep them alive, but the load balancing is done by nginx.

Comment: Anyways, as a tip for "strengthening your api", check memory usage and ensure you're not leaking memory.

Comment: Do you really need to hit the DB 10000+/sec. Sounds like an opportunity to use http://hapijs.com/tutorials/caching

Comment: @MattHarrison sadly they're writes not reads - so no caching. 10000r/s are the worst case - but the server shouldn't buckle under the load

Comment: I was wondering if you improved on this further.

Comment: @manonthemat added an answer ...

Comment: @PhilippKyeck can you tell me what is the load testing framework you used, the UI looks good?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just used a combination of node's `http` and the `body-parser` module to achieve what I needed.

But I think that this was only viable, because my application had just two endpoint (one `GET`, one `POST`).

If your application logic is rather complicated and you want to stick with `hapi`, think about using a load-balancer and dividing the load to multiple VMs.

Loadtest results (new setup on an even smaller DO droplet):

[image: loadtest results]

Comment: can you tell me what is the load testing framework you used, the UI looks good?

Comment: @Stacklearner it is not a framework but a service - called https://loader.io/. you can start for free and if you need more, pay money to "go pro".